# How do I validate Access Tokens in IdentityServer4

Tags: access-token, identityserver4

I had previously used IdentityServer3 for a project and created a nice login flow utilizing the accesstokenvalidation endpoint. This seems to not be available in IdentityServer4.

What am I supposed to use?

I found the AccessTokenValidation Nuget but it doesn't appear to add an endpoint or maybe I have it configured wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Login flow" and "access token" aren't really things that should go together. Can you describe in more detail this flow please?

As for the accesstokenvalidation endpoint, to validate an access token in IDS4 world you'd use the introspection endpoint.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I generalized too much. My old login flow was: user enters username/pass, that is sent to IDS3, accesstoken returned, that is sent to azure mobile app custom action, mobile app server validates access token and generates zumo token sending that back to the original client. But in any event, I figured out that the introspection endpoint was what to use, the documentation is totally lacking for it though, I wasn't aware it returned profile data/claims until I used it. Thanks!

Comment: You'll find that the documentation  is fairly light for standard endpoints because they behave as per the OIDC spec.